# Flask blueprints cannot import module

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm learning Blueprints for Flask, but I am having trouble with importing the correct modules. This is my setup:

Folder structure:

```
- app.py
  templates/
  nomad/
     - __init__.py
     - nomad.py
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from nomad.nomad import nblueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(nblueprint)
```

nomad.py

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint, abort
from app import app

nblueprint = Blueprint('nblueprint', __name__, template_folder='templates')

# Routes for this blueprint
@app.route ....
```

`__init__.py` is empty

The error I'm getting: `ImportError: cannot import name nblueprint`. I know my import statement is probably wrong, but what should it be and why?

**EDIT**:

If I remove `from app import app`, then I can successfully import `nblueprint` in app.py. But I need `app` in nomad.py because it needs to handle routes. Why is that line causing issues with importing, and how would I get around this?

Answer (score 4):

Blueprints is for define application route so you don't need to use app instance and blueprint in same place for route defination.

```
#nomad.py
@nblueprint.route('/')
```

You are getting error because while you register the blueprint at the same time you use app instance. So as you said when you remove the `from app ...` it solve the problem.

The recommend way is define your view for that blueprint in blueprint package in your example `nomad` package, it should be like this:

```
...
  nomad/
        __init__.py
        views.py
#nomad/__init__.py
nblueprint = Blueprint(...)
#nomad/views.py
from . import nblueprint
@nblueprint.route('/')
...
```